# Display items column wise in listbox

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone

In my application, I have binded my images stored in a observable collection in my view model to a list box on the xaml, the result is vertical scroll list (one column), whereas I want to display the images in 2 column view. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Though I have not used it, I think [WrapPanel](http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/WP7-WrapPanel-in-depth) is what you are looking for

Comment: I tried wrappanel with scrollviewer. It works perfectly, but then how to integrate wrappanel with listbox? As I want the items to be data binded to a list. Or is there any other way in which I would not have to use listbox? Just exploring it right now. Hope I get it right :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I achieved it finally. Kept the size of my Image such that only two images are wrapped in the the Wrappanel in one row, making it two columns.

```
        <ScrollViewer>
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ImageList}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ImageTemplate}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <toolkit:WrapPanel />
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            </ItemsControl>
        </ScrollViewer>
```